# `TWaitResult.wrIOCompletion` is undocumented. Can anyone provide usage tips?

Tags: delphi

`TWaitResult.wrIOCompletion` is [undocumented](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.SyncObjs.TWaitResult). Does anyone know when and how it's used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is used only on Windows, by `THandleObject` (and its descendants `TEvent`, `TSimpleEvent`, `TMutex`, and `TSemaphore`) in the following methods:

1. [`THandleObject.WaitFor()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SyncObjs.THandleObject.WaitFor).  When the object is created with `UseCOMWait` set to True, the wait is handled by the Win32 API [`CoWaitForMultipleHandles()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680732.aspx) function, where `wrIOCompletion` is returned if `RPC_S_CALLPENDING` is reported. When `UseCOMWait` is False instead, the wait is handled by the Win32 API [`WaitForMultipleObjectsEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687028.aspx) function <sup>1</sup>.
2. [`THandleObject.WaitForMultiple()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SyncObjs.THandleObject.WaitForMultiple). `wrIOCompletion` is returned if the `UseCOMWait` parameter is True and [`CoWaitForMultipleHandles()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680732.aspx) reports `RPC_S_CALLPENDING`, or when `UseCOMWait` is False and [`WaitForMultipleObjectsEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687028.aspx) reports `WAIT_IO_COMPLETION`.

Either way, the meaning is the same <sup>2</sup>:

> The wait was ended by one or more user-mode asynchronous procedure calls (APC) queued to the thread

Refer to MSDN for more details about APC queues:

[Asynchronous Procedure Calls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681951.aspx)

[Alertable I/O](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363772.aspx)

In a nutshell, an Alertable I/O or APC operation allows a user-defined operation/function to be queued in a thread so it will be called by the thread when in a safe state to make such a call.  `wrIOCompletion` indicates that the thread that is calling `WaitFor/Multiple()` had to stop waiting before the timeout elapsed so it could execute one or more queued Alertable/APC functions.  The thread will have to call `WaitFor/Multiple()` again to finish waiting on its desired object(s) <sup>3</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup>: `THandleObject.WaitFor()` does not currently handle `WAIT_IO_COMPLETION` (bug?) when `UseCOMWait` is false.  It will return `wrError` instead (and the value of the [`THandleObject.LastError`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SyncObjs.THandleObject.LastError) property will not be assigned!)

<sup>2</sup>: the [`CoWaitForMultipleHandles()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680732.aspx) documentation describes `RPC_S_CALLPENDING` as "*The timeout period elapsed before the required handle or handles were signaled*", but that would be a more appropriate description for `RPC_E_TIMEOUT` instead. (documentation error?)

<sup>3</sup>: in practice `wrIOCompletion` should never happen, because [`CoWaitForMultipleHandles()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680732.aspx) is never called with the `COWAIT_ALERTABLE` flag:

> If the COWAIT_ALERTABLE flag is set in dwFlags, a value of WAIT_IO_COMPLETION indicates the wait was ended by one or more user-mode asynchronous procedure calls (APC) queued to the thread.

And [`WaitForMultipleObjectsEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687028.aspx) is never called with its `bAlertable` parameter set to True:

> bAlertable [in]
>   If this parameter is TRUE and the thread is in the waiting state, the function returns when the system queues an I/O completion routine or APC, and the thread runs the routine or function. Otherwise, the function does not return and the completion routine or APC function is not executed.

These conditions are needed to trigger the `wrIOCompletion` result. I have opened a bug report for this in [Quality Portal](https://quality.embarcadero.com):

[RSP-14047 THandleObject never returns wrIOCompletion](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-14047).